Get return type of an interface conditionally
I have many interfaces like IWorkExperience, IEducation etc. that builds a resume interface (IResume). I have many interfaces for resume section but given interfaces are for example. Please see the interfaces below;
I am trying to get items (array of the type of interface) as return type of a function.
Here is my function that is not working as expected.
How can I get type of IWorkExperience or IEducation as a return type of this function to get the items in resume?
Thanks.
export interface IWorkExperience {
  unique: string;
  jobTitle: string | null;
  company: string | null;
  city: string | null;
  country: string | null;
  from: string | null;
  to: string | null;
  description: string | null;
  position: number;
  height: number;
}

export interface IEducation {
  unique: string;
  school: string | null;
  field: string | null;
  degree: string | null;
  city: string | null;
  country: string | null;
  from: string | null;
  to: string | null;
  current: boolean;
  description: string | null;
  position: number;
  height: number;
}
export interface IResume {
  workExperiences: IWorkExperience[];
  educations: IEducation[];
}

export const getSectionDataByType = (type: string, resume: IResume): any[] => {
  let section: any;

  Object.keys(resume).map((k, i) => {
    if (k === type) {
      section = resume[k as keyof typeof resume];
    }
  });

  return section;
}```




Object.keys(…).map(k => { if (k == …) … }) doesn't make any sense. You just want return resume[type]! (Not sure it's even worth writing a function for that)

Don't use type: string but rather type: keyof IResume. Then instead of returning any[], make the function generic on the type of the type parameter, and the correct return type will fall out of it

@Bergi Thank you so much for the comment. I am now trying to make it generic   as per your instructions but I couldn't. Could you please help me on this issue?

Can you [edit] your question to include your attempt?

I have solved it by using union types. I am posting my solution in case of someone else has the same issue. You can find the playground solution.
type EntityType = "workExperiences" | "educations";

function getItems<T extends EntityType>(type: T, resume:IResume) {
   return resume[type];
}

const a  = getItems("workExperiences", resume);
const b = getItems("educations", resume);

